# Encountered error while testing graphviz installation: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'

Tags: python, installation, graphviz, nonetype

I've installed Grpahviz, and i was supposed to run a testing code to check if i've installed all packages successfully, then i got this error. I didn't find anyone that has this same error as i got, could someone tell me the logic behind the happening of this error and how can i solve this ? thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKH5N.png)